# How to display arbitrary text in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3 app, I have a form that asks users to write a note. For example, the text the user inputs might be

```
@note = "This is a note\n\nwith whitespace."
```

How do I make this actually render as

```
This is a note

with whitespace.
```

when I display the note in my view? (I'm looking for a general solution, not one that simply replaces `\n` with `<br />` or such.)

Comment: What about using the `<pre>` tag

Comment: what about <%= @note.html_safe %> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the <pre> tag as @Moak suggests

Use CSS for line wrapping:

```
pre {
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4 - 6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 
  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: If the user types in a really long sentence, how would I get this to automatically wrap to the next line if I use the <pre> tag?

Comment: Nevermind, found the CSS here! http://www.longren.org/2006/09/27/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your view, either:

```
<pre><%= @note %></pre>
```

Or:

```
<%= @note.gsub(/\n/, '<br />') %>
```